# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am getting this error while building APK

```
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable
```

Tried following possible solutions-
Invalidate cache and restart Android Studio
Adding this line to gradle.properties: org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m

But none of them works for me.

Comment: Welcome! Run your build with `--stacktrace` and attach the stack trace, please.

Answer (score 1):

I also had that problem and I fixed it.

the solution is to check all your layout files, there are missing <? on the first line or etc, just check it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I commented a line in the layout file and it led to the error.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked this:
Make sure all your layouts have an id, for example

```
android:id="@+id/mainScreen"
```

check that all the layouts have one, my problem was that the main layout did not have an id, i asigned one and then worked.