# I terminate my android code but it has a problem

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm new to android studio coding
it gives me this message:

Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable

Someone told me to change the gradle numbers but it did not help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if any layout contains any error regarding this tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

also check this below question as it's similar

[A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71205989/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-com-android-build-gradle-internal-res-parseli)